# copyonwritearraylist strange error

Tags: java, list, copyonwritearraylist

I have this code:

```
int rnd1=Rnd.get(players.size());
int rnd2=Rnd.get(players.size());

while(rnd2==rnd1)
    rnd2=Rnd.get(players.size());


for(L2PcInstance player : players)
{
    if(player != players.get(rnd1) && player != players.get(rnd2))
           players.remove(player);
}
```

And I have this error:

> Exception in thread "GeneralSTPool-8" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
>           at java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
>           at java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
>           at net.sf.l2j.gameserver.model.RandomFight.pickPlayers(RandomFight.java:89)
>           at net.sf.l2j.gameserver.model.RandomFight$pickPlayers.run(RandomFight.java:270)
>           at net.sf.l2j.gameserver.ThreadPoolManager$RunnableWrapper.run(ThreadPoolManager.java:85)
>           at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(Unknown Source)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

What is going on here? Line 89 is this : `for(L2PcInstance player : players)`.
This shouldn't appeared since `rnd.get()` is from `0` to `players.size() - 1`.

Comment: The list is no longer the same size after you remove items from it.

Comment: @kiheru this is a COW list though, it shouldn't matter

Comment: @fge COW can still throw exceptions when accessing indexes out of bounds. This is not a ConcurrentModification exception

Comment: Forgot to say that Rnd.get(int n) method , automatically includes from 0 to n-1. :S

Comment: Well, if you remove an element of the list and one of your random indices is size - 1, then you can get this error, can't you?

Comment: @kiheru uh, yeah, brain fart, sorry

Answer (score 1):

The intent seems to remove all but the two selected players from the list. There are simpler ways to do it. For example:

```
players.retainAll(Arrays.asList(players.get(rnd1), players.get(rnd2));
```

This also does not have problems with concurrent modifications, in case that was the reason you use `CopyOnWriteArrayList`.

The reason for the error, as already said in comments was: the player indices are generated on an initial list, and at that point they are indeed valid. The removal loop, however decreases the list size, and the previously generated indices can end outside the valid range.